# Size of the Flash Builder 4.5 application after packaging with iTunes

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios-4.2, flash-builder, flex4.5

Creating an iOS app in Flash Builder 4.5 which is a small "Hello World" App, working fine on emulator and iOS devices. Before packaging the size of the application is 532 Kb but after packaging in iTunes the .ipa file generated which have size is 12 Mb.

I want to know that how and why the file size increases and does the size consumes more battery power and memory usage??

Can any one explain??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, because if you want to run the flex apps in iphone or android, you must install the runtime environment first, the air or flex in mobile runtime will occupy about 10-18 MB memory.

Comment: thanks, after searching and analyzing so much conclusion is cz air consumes 10-12 MB memory at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The file size increases not because it eats up memory, but because AIR apps are packaged for iOS along with the AIR runtime code, which is around 11 MB

On Android, the AIR runtime is 6 MB, and you do not need to package it with your app as there is a separate runtime download in Android Market (You can package AIR with your app in FB 4.5)